# Связать 3 таблицы MySql

Tags: mysql

Есть таблицы

```
  users   |   socials    |  employers
 ---------|--------------|-------------
 id(Pk)   |  id(Pk)      |  id(Pk)
 email    |  user_id     |  facebook_id
 name     |  facebook_id |  product_id
 pass     |  auth_token  |  date
```

как можно соединить эти 3 таблицы чтобы получить *product_id* , *facebook_id* по *user_id* пользователя.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

как вы описали, так и соединять. на почти живом английском языке:

```
select * from users
left join socials on socials.user_id = users.id
left join employers on employers.facebook_id = socials.facebook_id
```